# public static double array method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static, double

In using a top-down organizational structure in ava, I defined a static method to be used later in the main method. It is a double array method, which makes use of arguments from other arrays. However, I'm given an error every time I try to compile. I've tried various solutions, including using a for statement, but cannot seem to fix it.

```
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass) {
    return ((6.67 * Math.pow(10, -17) * mass) / Math.pow(radius, 2)); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't even return an array... Omit the brackets if you intend to return double and how would a for loop do anything?

Comment: you are trying to multiply an array. you can't do that. Also, `pow` takes a single value as parameter, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the method defined to return an array. It looks lIke in the end you want the method to create a new array and fill each index with the calculated gravity for the argument indexes in their respective arrays? If so, you are definitely going to need a for loop to iterate through the indexes of the argumentime arrays. You also need to define a new array (do this before the for loop) use the formula you have already within the for loop. Once your array is complete, return the array name. Hope that makes sense and helps!

Comment: Thanks! That really helped. I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 1):

This does not return an array nor should it take array parameters. Try

```
public static double calcGravity(double radius, double mass) {
    return ((6.67 * Math.pow(10, -17) * mass) / Math.pow(radius, 2)); 
}
```

If you want to calculate the gravity from `radius` and `mass` arrays try

```
double[] radius = // Whatever (both should have same length)
double[] mass = // Whatever
double[] gravity = new double[radius.length];
for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++) {
  gravity[i] = calcGravity(radius[i], mass[i]);
}
```

Comment: I understand, but I need it to be an array so that I might print the values within that array, each in order. The method should be able to hold nine values, each of which I can access. Also, the radius and mass parameters are taken from array described in the main method.

Comment: Look at the second part of the code. You have an array of gravity values in order.

Comment: Oh wait, I understand now. Thank You.